# Why does not work return C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
public static Array readCVS(string absolutePath)
{
    string[,] temperatureMatrix = new string[384, 288];
    string value;

    using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(absolutePath))
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader);
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        int y = 1;

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            for (int x = 1; csv.TryGetField<string>(x, out value); x++)
            {
                x = x - 1;
                temperatureMatrix[1, 1] = value;
            }
            y = y + 1;
        }
        return temperatureMatrix;
    }
}
```

So `return t;` does not work, I mean it does not return array, also I tried to set break point here, then I can not see structure of filled array

Comment: Please post code that is closer to real code. Too much broken and missing here.

Comment: your code has compilation errors too. first fix them

Comment: Please read [mcve] guidance and update code in the post with all missing declarations. Not possible to reason what problem you have otherwise.

Comment: I posted full code of function

Comment: I updated question. Look please again

Comment: what is CsvReader class doing?

Comment: It does not matter, problem is in return

Comment: use try catch .

Comment: let me know why it does not matter?? are you asking for help or giving order to fix your problem . in you entire method you are using CsvReader  class object, how can anybody tell you about the problem then ?

Comment: Do you realize that you are writing the string extracted by the CsvReader field always in the same spot of the array overwriting the previous value?. And what about that _x = x - 1_ inside the for loop that uses x to traverse your fields? It seems that you enter an infinite loop here

Comment: About `x` is because  loop works with `1` but array with `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointes by Steve, you code seems to be incorrect at many places.
I want to point out one more thing, better to use `List` not `Array`, because if you have large file, you will get index out of range exception. and `List` will give you infinite length.

```
public static List<string> readCVS(string absolutePath)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    string value;
    using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(absolutePath))
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader);
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; csv.TryGetField<string>(i, out value); i++)
            {
                result.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I dont know why were you using `y` in your code. It was of no use, we were just decrementing it .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code enters an infinite loop in the for used to read the column values of a line extracted by the CsvReader.

I think you should change your code to remove the decrement of x inside the for loop (not clear the reason for that line but surely it doesn't allow the x to advance to the next column of the input line).

Finally you should set the values of the matrix using correctly the y (for rows) and x (for columns)

```
public static Array readCVS(string absolutePath)
{
    string[,] temperatureMatrix = new string[384, 288];
    string value;
    using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(absolutePath))
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader);
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        int y = 0;
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            for (int x = 0; csv.TryGetField<string>(x, out value); x++)
                temperatureMatrix[x, y] = value;

            y = y + 1;
        }
        return temperatureMatrix;
    }
}
```

I have also changed the initial indexing from 1 to 0 both for x and y. In Net arrays (also the multidimensional ones) starts at index 0 not 1.

Be warned also that this code is very dependant from the exact structure of your input file. If you ever get a file with more that 288 lines or with a single line with more than 384 single temp values the code will crash with an index out of range exception.

Comment: Why did you chanaged positions x,y here `temperatureMatrix[y, x]`?

Comment: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: It depends on how many lines are in the file (384 or 288?) I assume 384 lines, just change the order if it is not the case

Comment: By horizontal I have 384 and corresponding 288 by vertical

Comment: So you have 288 lines thus I need to change the x, y order